# Applescript - Copy Image, Paste as Icon

Tags: macos, applescript, finder

For organizational purposes, via a hotkey, I'd like to be able to quickly copy a selected image file (as is in Finder), then paste it as the icon for a selected folder, without having to go into 'Get Info' for the folder.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need two scripts: one to copy image (not a file but image itself), other to paste image as icon.

Copy image:

```
tell application "Finder"
    open selection using (path to application "Preview") -- open with Preview
end tell

tell application "Preview"
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "a" using command down -- select all
        keystroke "c" using command down -- copy
        keystroke "w" using command down -- close window
    end tell
end tell
```

Paste image as icon:

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "i" using command down -- open info

        -- set focus on icon image
        tell process "Finder"
            set img to (image 1 of scroll area 1 of front window)
            set focused of img to true
        end tell

        keystroke "v" using command down -- insert image
        keystroke "w" using command down -- close window
    end tell
end tell
```

Than you can bind these two scripts to some hotkeys. I use FastScripts for that purpose.
**Note 1**: you may need to enable access for assistive devices under the SystemPreferences -> Accessibility

**Note 2**: if some parts of the scripts are not work (for example Preview opened, but image  not selected, etc.) you should try to play with delays.